# Macbook white A1181: Startup manager, just mouse pointer

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I'm dealing with my friend's Macbook White A1181. Original hard drive died a few weeks ago so we installed a brand new Samsung 840 EVO (256GB).

I've read several tutorials on how to reinstall OSX on a new fresh hard drive without luck. After the chime, I press alt/option key then the mouse pointer appears and that's all. I waited for ˜30 minutes and nothing happend.

Also tried with all those key combinations and nothing: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255. If I didn't hit any key, I got a flashing folder icon with a question sign.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: and you know that the flashing folder with question mark says no system installed or found?

Comment: I know this thread is quite old, but I have the same problem/situation with *Masterl1nk*, and I can't find concrete answer to this problem yet. I already created Mac OS installer in a USB stick like *quietquake* said, but holding the Option key does not show up list of devices, just white screen with mouse pointer. If I don't press any key, a flashing folder with a Question mark appears. Exactly like the situation of *Masterl1nk*. My Mac is **Apple MacBook Pro "Core Duo" 2.0 15" with Mac OS X Snow Leopard** Hope there's anyone there who can give us the answer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either insert a Mac OS installer DVD in the optical drive, or a Mac OS installer USB drive in a USB port. You then need to boot from the installer by holding the option key while starting the computer up, then clicking the installer in the list of available devices.